# Php and curl verification

Tags: php, curl

I try use Curl for get content from other website and verificate , and if the verification it´s ok redir from website

My Code :

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://cp.panel.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "inUsername=".$_REQUEST['inUsername']."&inPassword=".$_POST['inPassword']."&csfr_token=".$_POST['csfr_token']."");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec ($curl);
$result2 = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

echo $result2;

$result="Invalid";

if (eregi($result,$result2)) 
{
print '{"login":"ok"}';
}
```

If with result i get from curl into eregi detect word **Invalid** , get response and no redirect , if get other response i can redir

The problem it´s i get nothing from curl and i don´t understand why happen this

Thank´s for the help , Regards !!!

Comment: You don't want to do this. Seriously.

Comment: use PREG, not EREG.  And white-list, don't black-list.  Account for cases where is valid, not all the ways it can be invalid.  i.e. HTTP 500 or other issues.

Comment: Yes i wan do it , why ?

Comment: No it´s crazy i think verificate login form by curl .....